# How do I zip an entire folder (with subfolders) and serve it through Flask without saving anything to disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, zip

I have a folder structure on my web server that I would like to serve as a zipped archive through Flask.

Serving a file through Flask is pretty straight forward through Flasks send_file:

```
return send_file(my_file,
                     attachment_filename=fileName,
                     as_attachment=True)
```

Zipping can get accomplished in various ways like with `shutil.make_archive` or `zipfile`, but i cannot figure out how to zip the whole directory in memory and then send it without saving anything to disk. `shutil.make_archive` seem to only be able to create archives on disk. The examples on `zipfile` found on the Internet are mainly about serving single files.

How would I tie this together in a single method without having to save everything to disk? Preferably using `BytesIO`.

Comment: Any feedback on how to improve this question would be appreciated. I had a really hard time figuring this out, and with three upvotes, it seems like a needed question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import time
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile
import os
from flask import send_file


@app.route('/zipped_data')
def zipped_data():
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    fileName = "my_data_dump_{}.zip".format(timestr)
    memory_file = BytesIO()
    file_path = '/home/data/'
    with zipfile.ZipFile(memory_file, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
          for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
                    for file in files:
                              zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
    memory_file.seek(0)
    return send_file(memory_file,
                     attachment_filename=fileName,
                     as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: Answering own questions is not discouraged. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Very helpful! In my case I was passing back zipped bytes from a block of code running on a remote machine and so my return was different. Used equivalent of `return memory_file.getvalue()` from the function running remotely and then wrote that returned item at local namespace using `wb` with `with open` and saving with `.zip` extension. In case maybe it will help others new to making the zipped files with Python, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54202259/8508004) helped in understanding the `memory_file.seek(0)` line.